# Wrong password reset link on email

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am using multi-auth on my project and my login pages are:

```
myurl.com/login
```

and

```
myurl.com/admin/login
```

The password reset routine on the `myurl.com/login` works fine. But when I try it on `myurl.com/admin/login`, the reset link that I am receiving on the email is still:

```
myurl.com/password/reset/XXXXXXXXXX
```

But it should be:

```
myurl.com/admin/password/reset/XXXXXXXXXX
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using custom guards ? if so, check if you had added your admin guard to `auth.php` config `resetting passwords` and defined the provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who gave time to answer.

Here's what solved my problem.

I have the entry below on `App\Notifications\AdminResetPassword`:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
  return (new MailMessage)
    ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
    ->action('Reset Password', url('admin/password/reset', $this->token))
    ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```

Then I defined this on my `App\Models\Admin`:

```
use App\Notifications\AdminResetPassword as ResetPasswordNotification;

public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
   $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

After this, my reset password link for both `/login` and `admin/login` are working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a specific route for the administrators password reset, a single route does not take all the guards if you did not indicate it in the code.
You must also specified it with if condition in notification in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController class by overwriting Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails trait function

```
    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateEmail($request);
        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
            $this->credentials($request)
        );

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                   ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                   : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
     }
```

// or the response function

```
    protected function sendResetLinkResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
                   ? new JsonResponse(['message' => trans($response)], 200)
                   : back()->with('status', trans($response));
    }
```

Verify if email belong to admin, and send the appropriate link
Personnaly i would update sendResetLinkEmail function and create another function to send link to admin Like this

```
    $guard = 'user';
    $user = User::query()->where('email', $email)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        $user = Admin::query()->where('email', $email)->first();
        $guard = 'admin';
    }
    if (!$user) {
        // This for another case
        //    $user = 
        //    $guard =
    }
    // and then, instead of 
    //     return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
    //                ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
    //                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request,    $response);

    // i will do

    if ($guard == 'user') {
        $success_response = $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response);
    } else if ($guard == 'admin') {
        $success_response = $this->createAdminResetResponseFunction($request, $response);
    } else {
        // Set one as default
        $success_response = $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response);
    }

    return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                ? $success_response
                : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
```